# Brewster's angle for Metal?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, metals, optical-materials

As metal has a high refraction index, it is possible to have Brewster's Angle for Metal when the light incident from the air? Is it possible to derive from any formula?

Answer (score 2):

So there is pseudo-Brewster angle for metals (Citation: Journal of Applied Physics 78, 4799 (1995); doi: 10.1063/1.359763):

> It is a subject of textbooks that the reflectivity of metals is a
> function of the angle of incidence and that it has a minimum for a
> given wavelength at the pseudo-Brewster angle. Consequently, the
> absorption is maximal at this angle and  can be much higher than the
> usual low absorption of metals for normal incidence.

Comment: ... and it's derived using the same Fresnel relations that are used to find Brewster's angle for glass.